# Table border-spacing not working

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to separate the images in this table with space, using the CSS border-spacing property, but for some reason it's not working. You can see how the images are still stuck together in the JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nKgnq/

I've tried hacking it by putting padding around the images instead, to no avail. How can I get these pictures apart?

The code to generate the table is here:

```
<div class="table-right">
    <table class="fixed-height fixed-width fixed-cell">
        <tr>
            <td class="valigned"><h3 class="date">Details</h3>
                <?php the_field('details');?>
            </td>
            <td class="valigned">
                <a href="<?php echo MultiPostThumbnails::get_post_thumbnail_url(get_post_type(), 'secondary-image');?>">
                    <img class="detail-image" src="<?php echo MultiPostThumbnails::get_post_thumbnail_url(get_post_type(), 'secondary-image');?>">
                </a>
            </td>
            <td class="valigned">
                <a href="<?php echo MultiPostThumbnails::get_post_thumbnail_url(get_post_type(), 'tertiary-image');?>">
                    <img class="detail-image" src="<?php echo MultiPostThumbnails::get_post_thumbnail_url(get_post_type(), 'tertiary-image');?>">
                </a>
            </td>
            <td class="valigned">
                <a href="<?php echo MultiPostThumbnails::get_post_thumbnail_url(get_post_type(), 'fourth-image');?>">
                    <img class="detail-image" src="<?php echo MultiPostThumbnails::get_post_thumbnail_url(get_post_type(), 'fourth-image');?>">
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post a fiddle with working images and just the part of the code that isn't working.

Comment: your jsfiddle is riddled with broken images etc.. the cleaner your jsfiddle is, the sooner we will be able to help you

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your css you apply `border-spacing:5px` to the `table-right` class, but your table doesn't use that, even though it's contained in the div you have that applied to, because you have

```
table { /* tables still need 'cellspacing="0"' in the markup */
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

in your css, which is a more specific selector and will over-write the inherited css from the div. if you make a class like

```
.table-spacing{
   border-spacing:5px;
}
```

you can apply that to your table tag

```
<table class="fixed-height fixed-width fixed-cell table-spacing">
```

and that will solve the problem in the way requested, I think

Comment: For me, `border-collapse: separate;` was being overwritten by `border-collapse: collapse;` which ended up being the culprit.

Comment: @RCNeil - you the real MVP

Comment: so `border-spacing` doesn't work unless `border-collapse: separate` is also used it seems ? http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-spacing.asp seems to say so

Comment: @DonCheadle: correct, see: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-spacing.asp

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to understand your jsFiddle, but generically, one method is to put padding on your `<td>` tags. Add an additional class, for example `rightpadding`, to the `<td>` tags you want extra padding on, then define it in your CSS.

```
.rightpadding
{
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

And your `<td>` tags would look like this:

```
<td class="valigned rightpadding">
```